# Map to instances of one class to instances of another using unordered_map

Tags: c++, hash, unordered-map

I have a simple code where four `Node`-type and two `Edge`-type variables are defined, and an unordered map is created to map the start edges onto their end edges. However, Visual Studio 2015 Professional is complaining about the following problem:

`The C++ Standard doesn't provide a hash for this type.`

Could you please help me how to solve this problem? My small code (which is an MWE, so the original purpose was other than introducing such a stupid map) is as follows:

```
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<unordered_map>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node
{
   public:
      Node(){};
      string label;
};

class Edge
{
   public:
      Edge(){};
      Node *start, *end;
};

int main()
{
   Edge* edge;
   Node* node;

   vector<Node*> nodes;
   vector<Edge*> edges;

   unordered_map<Node*,Edge*> n2e; 

   edge = new Edge();
   edges.push_back(edge);

   node = new Node();
   node->label = "A";
   edge->start = node;
   nodes.push_back(node);

   node = new Node();
   node->label = "B";
   edge->end = node;
   nodes.push_back(node);

   edge = new Edge();
   edges.push_back(edge);

   node = new Node();
   node->label = "C";
   edge->start = node;
   nodes.push_back(node);

   node = new Node();
   node->label = "D";
   edge->end = node;
   nodes.push_back(node);

   n2e[nodes[0]] = edges[0];
   n2e[nodes[2]] = edges[1];

   cout << n2e[nodes[0]]->start->label << "  " << n2e[nodes[0]]->end->label << endl;
   cout << n2e[nodes[2]]->start->label << "  " << n2e[nodes[2]]->end->label << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This compiled for me in VS2015 by replacing `#include <stdio.h>` (which isn't needed afaict) by `#include <string>` which was missing (it also compiles with [g++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/91c7418d9d921856))

Comment: @Borgleader, Thank you for checking this code. I can also compile it with g++ under Linux. So, I will check the original code and try to find out what causes the error.

Comment: Since you don't specify a hash class for your `unordered_map`, it will use `std::hash<Node*>`, which you also don't define.  Including `<string>` is likely including some form of hash that operates on the _pointer value_, and not what the pointer is pointing to, so the hash you're getting is probably not what you'd want.